# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call'). VITE + @react-pdf/renderer v3

Tags: reactjs, vite, renderer, react-pdf

## To recreate

Create React TS app with Vite

```
npm init vite@latest vite-project --template react
```

Create sample pdf document

```
import React from 'react';
import pdf from '@react-pdf/renderer';
const { Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet } = pdf;

// Create styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4',
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});

// Create Document Component
export const MyDocument = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page size='A4' style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>Section #1</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>Section #2</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);
```

Delete the contents of App.ts. And add the following code from @react-pdf/renderer's example

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { PDFViewer } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

const App = () => (
  <PDFViewer>
    <MyDocument />
  </PDFViewer>
);
```

Run the development server and check console for errors.

I tried to do it with create react app and everything worked fine. With Vite is that the error happens.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it!

You just need to manually install the following package.

```
npm i events
```